# Generate a random number in a php class

Tags: php, json, class, object

I am doing an exercise I found online to teach myself `php`. The program I am making is a "Guess the Number" game where I need to generate a random number to be guessed. I was successful in the exercise when not using a class and using `html` input boxes for the users input:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['number'])) {
    $number = $_POST['number'];
} else {
    $number = rand(1,99);
}

if($_POST["guess"]) {
    // grab the user input guess
    $guess  = $_POST['guess'];
    $number  = $_POST['number'];
    $output = '';
    static $count = 0; //Initialize count

    if ($guess < $number) { 
        $output .= "$guess" . "<br />" . "Guess Higher";
        $count++;
    } elseif($guess > $number) {       
        $output .= "$guess" . "<br />" . "Guess Lower";
        $count++;
    } elseif($guess == $number) {  
        $count++;    
        $output .= "$guess" . "<br />" . "You got it!" . "<br />" . "You guessed it in " . $count . " trials";
    }
} ?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Guess A Number</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="NumberGuess.php" method="post">
            <label for="guess">Guess A Number:</label><br/ >
            <input type="text" name="guess" />
            <input name="number" type="hidden" value="<?= $number ?>" />
            <input name="submit" type="submit" />
            <br/>
            <?php echo $output ?>
            <br/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, now I want to repeat the exercise using `json` as input and using classes/objects. I tried using `rand()` to generate the random number, however it causes an issue and the page won't load:

```
class NumberGuess {
    protected $guess = 0;
    const randNumber = rand(1,99);
    protected $isNumber = false;
    protected $higher = true;

    function __construct($inputGuess) {
        $this->guess = $inputGuess;
    }

    public function getResult() {
        $this->numberChecker();

        if($this->higher == true) {
            $this->higher = "higher";
        } elseif($this->higher == false) {
            $this->higher = "lower";
        }

        if($this->isNumber == false) {
            return $this->guess . " is incorrect, " . "try guessing " . $this->higher;
        } elseif($this->isNumber == true) {
            return $this->guess . " is correct!";
        }
    }

    private function numberChecker() {
        if($this->guess < self::randNumber) {
            $this->higher = true;
            $this->isNumber = false;
        } elseif($this->guess > self::randNumber) {
            $this->higher = false;
            $this->isNumber = false;
        } elseif($this->guess == self::randNumber) {
            $this->higher = false;
            $this->isNumber = true;
        }
    }
}

if ( isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ) {
    $inputString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    $inputGuess = intval($inputString);
}

$myGuess = new NumberGuess($inputGuess);
echo json_encode($myGuess->getResult());
```

Could someone please explain to me how I can generate a random number in a class using `json`?

Comment: this is wrong `const randNumber = rand(1,99);` turn on basic error checking, if you do you will get a fatal error

Comment: Thanks @nogad, but could you tell me what is wrong about it?

Comment: the error you get is: "PHP Fatal error:  Constant expression contains invalid operations in" the manual explains why: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php "The value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a property, or a function call. "

Comment: Okay but if I change it to protected/public/static I still get an error

Comment: just create one in the constructor just add: `$this->randNumber= rand(1,99);` then use `$this->randNumber`

Comment: Yes that works but the only issue is then the randNumber changes after every guess

Comment: as it would in your original code if it was valid

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PHP` [rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) or [mt_rand()](http://php.net/mt_rand) function to generate random number between the range.

> `rand()` Syntax

```
int rand ( void )
#OR
int rand ( int $min , int $max )
```

> `mt_rand()` Syntax

```
int mt_rand ( void )
#OR
int mt_rand ( int $min , int $max )
```

**Note :** You can use `JavaScript` [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) function for instant Generate random number. Or You can use `Ajax` to generate Random number using `PHP`.